# Is it possible to add extra settings into the Email settings [picture]

Tags: email, defaults, entitysubscription

Is it possible to add a table of values into the default Salesforce Email settings window?
I wanted to add a Table section into the area marked RED in the picture.

[image: PICTURE]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is URL hacking one of the option. I can't think of any!

Comment: You cant modify these setup screens. What will this table contain?

Comment: This table would have contained subscriptions to delivery notifications for certain stages that a product has reached. The user can check the boxes in the table if they want subscription mails.

Comment: I suppose for something like that you go for a separate vf page. It cant be done on this page.

Comment: @AslamK Can u put that as an answer? However easy it may sound :) I'm gonna accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to modify these setup pages in Salesforce. 
Better to go for a custom page to handle this.

You can create a custom object to save the user preferences, and create a visualforce page on top of this. The user can visit this page and set his/her preferences. You can even put the link to this VF page somewhere convenient for the users to go and update - like a sidebar link, or link on the user's detail page.